# Node.js Heap Snapshots: neither node-inspector nor nodetime will give me one :(

Tags: node.js

So, my current theory for my trouble with my app is a memory leak.
I'm trying to get a heap snapshot to investigate but...

When I try to use [node-inspector](https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial), there is no Profiles tab:

[image]

And when I use nodetime and press "Take Heap Snapshot" on the Memory Profiler tool, no output appears. Note that the output from the "npm install nodetime" looks good: http://pastebin.com/ZGk6ZuNL

And here are the modules I'm using: http://pastebin.com/UFS6jW5X

Comment: In Nodetime do you hit 'Confirm' after 'Take heap snapshot'and then give it some time? Confirmation step and the note are there to make sure it is not accidentally pressed, because V8 heap profiler, which is used underneath may double used memory size when taking the snapshot.

Comment: Wow, that was simple and dumb of me. The "confirm" step felt like something that was supposed to happen AFTER the heap snapshot, since it immediately tells me that snapshots will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this module? Has more commits on github. 
https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent